# Intermittent soft clutch 64 reg ranger

Tags: clutch-hydraulics

I have a 64 reg Ranger the clutch pedal keeps going soft at times and this morning went to the bottom and couldn’t get going until I managed to pump the peddle.
The fluid was change a couple of weeks ago when this started and master cylinder changed yesterday. Any ideas please ?

Comment: A failing seal in slave cylinder ?

Comment: First of all, check the fluid level in the clutch master cylinder reservoir.  If it's low that's a sign of a leak but you should be able to top it off and keep going for a little while.  Otherwise, you have a leak in the system that is allowing air to enter.  Could be the seal at either the master or the slave cylinders or a bad line or fitting.